# Size Normalization for segmented character images

Tags: matlab, normalization, preprocessor, image-segmentation

I've already do a normalization using padarray (code as follows), but the result for the next process (feature extraction) isn't good enough. Because it's not exactly the segmented part features, but also including the pad part.

[image]
-sample image (segmented characters)

I need to normalize only the segmented character of images, put it centered, and squared (it supposed to be [64 64]). It also should preserve the aspect ratio, without stretching or distorting the image, so the character image will be keep proportional.

```
% Normalization done using pad
function p = pad (im)
nrows = size(im,1);
ncols = size(im,2);

d = abs(ncols-nrows);    % difference between ncols and nrows:
if(mod(d,2) == 1)        % if difference is an odd number
    if (ncols > nrows)   % we add a row at the end
        im = [im; zeros(1, ncols)];
        nrows = nrows + 1;
    else                 % we add a col at the end
        im = [im zeros(nrows, 1)];
        ncols = ncols + 1;
    end
end

if ncols > nrows
    im = padarray(im, [(ncols-nrows)/2 0]);
else
    im = padarray(im, [0 (nrows-ncols)/2]);
end

im = imresize(im, [64 64]);

% figure, imshow (im);

p = (im);

% Here im is a 5x5 matix, not perfectly centered 
% because we added an odd number of columns: 3
% Original code by Sembei Norimaki, modified by Ana
```

Some modification of this code, still not work. So, I need a suggestion for this code modification or any recommended method for this case.

Any Help would be very appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: it's still not clear to me what you're trying to do exactly. Are you trying to trim the images and copy them in the center of a 64x64 zero array? Are your images all guaranteed to be less than 64x64?

Comment: What do you mean by copy them into zero array? Could you explain more?    
|| I need to normalize (resize) all images into [64 64] with still preserve the aspect ratio.   || The size are various, there are less and bigger than 64x64. I could use "imresize", but it makes the images distorting or stretching which means it give a disproportionate result.  || Do you have any suggestion? Thanks for the respond.

Comment: If you use the `imresize` which only takes an image argument and a scalar (as opposed to a 2-element vector), then the aspect ratio will remain the same. Do you only care about the aspect ratio, or do you want the letters to be of correct size with respect to each other? (i.e in your example, the 'parts' do not fill their boxes. Is that intentional?

Comment: I need the letter in correct size (proportional) but normalized into the same size (64x64) || That's the dilema. At first, I thought I just need to make the segmented images to be square by using pad (as shown in image). ||  But after get the result, it's not good for feature extraction (because it process the segmented character include the pad, make the feature isn't accurately belong to the segmented character). || Then, I need a better normalization method. It supposed to be make all segmented character fill the whole boxes part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure that's what you're after, but here goes:

Example: (assumes images 'alif.png', 'dod.png', 'ha.png', and 'uau.png' in the path).

```
%%%% in file 'processLetter.m' %%%%
function L = processLetter (L)
  %% Step 1 : Trim padding.
  tmp = find (L); % Get linear indices of nonzero elements
  [Row_subs, Col_subs] = ind2sub (size (L), tmp); % Convert to row / col subscripts
  L = L(min (Row_subs) : max (Row_subs), min (Col_subs) : max (Col_subs)); % trim

  %% Resize such that the largest dimension is scaled to 64 pixels
  Rows = size (L, 1); Cols = size (L, 2);
  if Rows > Cols; Resize_vec = [64, NaN]; 
  else            Resize_vec = [NaN, 64]; 
  end

  L = imresize (L, Resize_vec);
  Rows = size (L, 1); Cols = size (L, 2);

  %% Pad smallest dimension to 64 pixels
  if Rows > Cols; 
    LeftPad  = abs (floor ((64 - Cols) / 2 ));
    RightPad = abs (floor ((Cols - 64) / 2 ));
    L = padarray (L, [0, LeftPad ], 'pre' );
    L = padarray (L, [0, RightPad], 'post');
  else
    TopPad    = abs (floor ((64 - Rows) / 2 ));
    BottomPad = abs (floor ((Rows - 64) / 2 ));
    L = padarray (L, [TopPad,    0], 'pre' );
    L = padarray (L, [BottomPad, 0], 'post');
  end 

  L = mat2gray (L);
  L = L > 0.5;  % in case L was a 'double' matrix -- needed in Octave
end
%%%% end of file 'processLetter.m' %%%%
```

Then call with:

```
Alif = imread ('alif.png'); Dod  = imread ('dod.png'); 
Ha   = imread ('ha.png'  ); Uau  = imread ('uau.png');
Alif = double (Alif); Dod = double (Dod); Ha = double (Ha); Uau = double (Uau); % if using octave -- octave 'imresize' function throws an error if image is logical instead of double
subplot (2, 4, 1); imagesc (Alif); axis equal off; colormap gray;
subplot (2, 4, 2); imagesc (Dod ); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 3); imagesc (Ha  ); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 4); imagesc (Uau ); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 5); imagesc (processLetter (Alif)); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 6); imagesc (processLetter (Dod) ); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 7); imagesc (processLetter (Ha)  ); axis equal off;
subplot (2, 4, 8); imagesc (processLetter (Uau) ); axis equal off;
```

Result:

[image]

Is this the kind of thing you were after?

Comment: Note: above code is Octave compatible, but you may have to explicitly load the `image` package first, as `imresize()` relies on it.

Comment: (alphabet images converted from here: http://www.joaoleitao.com/names-arabic/arabic-alphabet-abc/ )

Comment: I am using matlab actually. || Thanks for the code you've provided. I'll try.

Comment: Yes, but, is *this* what you're trying to do?? Are your letters *meant* to look zoomed-in so as to fill their 'boxes' as much as possible? Or is the "Ha" and "Uau" too big compared to the "Dod" for example?

Comment: For Now on, it's great enough. That's what I'm trying to do. || Thanks in advance :) @Tasos